# Load different views in a controller using HTML ActionLink in MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having a problem with **loading difference views by using @Html.ActionLink**.
I've attached some screen shots here to explain the problem.

[image]

when I click on the "Home" button Its loading properly, But when I click on the "Contact" button its load the page **but JavaScript, jQuery NOT Working**

```
@{
   Html.Raw("<li class='k-block'>");  

   @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "k-button" }) 

       Html.Raw("</li>");

   Html.Raw("<li class='k-block'>");  

   @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "k-button" }) 

   Html.Raw("</li>");
```

[image]

**Can you please tell me what would be the mistake I've made..**

Comment: Just for clarification: It is called **ActionLink**, because when you click it - you open Action. You cannot load View.

Comment: It's work for "Index" action method. 
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
------------------------------------------------------
But not  for "Contact" action method.
public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return Index();
        }
--------------------------------------------------
I like to know the reason to this behavior.
Thank you..

Comment: Your contact method is in contact controller? Or is it in Home controller?

Comment: Both are in the Home controller

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "k-button" })` should be `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Contact", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "k-button" })`

Comment: I've tried your code , but the same result.. Thank you

Comment: Where is the Contact method defined? Can you post that code as well

Comment: its also in the Home controller.

public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

       

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }

Comment: check the console for any errors..what is in Contact View

Answer (score 1):

Just write it like

```
@Html.ActionLink("ActionLink", "ActionName","ControllerName" }, new { @class = "ClassName" }) 



@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact","Home" }, new { @class = "k-button" })
```

Comment: That also the same result. JQuery not working properly.